# qProgressBar как изменить стандартный цвет и текст во время работы программы

Tags: c++, qt

В общем имею цель добавить в программу qProgressBar но с возможностью его изменения цвета и надписи текста в нём элемент установлен в ui через дизайнер.

Попробовал так :

```
     ui->pB_DD1->setFormat("% неисправен");
     QPalette p = palette();
     p.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(Qt::red));
     ui->pB_DD1->setPalette(p);
```

Ошибок не выводит но при этом ни чего не меняется.

Что я делаю не так ??

Вот ещё вариант :

```
ui->progressBar->setFormat("% неисправен");
QPalette p = palette();
QPalette pal = ui->progressBar->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(Qt::red));
ui->progressBar->setPalette(pal);
```

Не сработало

---

можно через CSS -стили  :

```
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("*{background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black; }");
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("*{color: rgb(255, 255, 0); background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(100,0,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(200,0,0,255)); border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px;}");
ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("*::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(0,200,255,255), stop: 1 rgba(0,0,255,255));}"); //  это градиент
```

НО от такого метода есть проблемма нет полной аналогии с предшественником (моя цель сменить только цвет линии).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создайте палету через new. QPalette* p = new QPalette(palette());

Comment: @goldstar_labs  создал, но теперь ругается     `ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QProgressBar::setPalette(QPalette*&)'
          ui->pB_DD1->setPalette(p);`

Comment: `ui->pB_DD1->setPalette(*p); ` вот так пробуйте

Comment: @goldstar_labs дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем я сделал через реализацию CSS-стиля , вот код :

```
// Конопка "нажимаем"
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->progressBar->setFormat(" неисправен");
    ui->progressBar->setValue(1000);
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;"
                                   "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                                   "border-radius: 5px;"
                                   "border-width: 3px;"
                                   "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                   "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                    "}"
                                   "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
}
// кнопка "стукаем" 
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

     ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(QString()); // возвращаем "стартовый" стиль 
     ui->progressBar->setValue(500);
     ui->progressBar->setFormat(QString("%p [кг/см2]"));
}
```

**Старт** запуск программы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**после** нажатия кнопки "нажимаем"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**после** нажатия кнопки "стукаем"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]